# Rails4: Adding Pages to a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a Shop's Controller:

```
http://localhost:3000/shops/testing
```

and i want to add an `about` and `policy` page to the existing shop

```
http://localhost:3000/shops/testing/about
http://localhost:3000/shops/testing/policy
```

Do i have to generate a seperate model or views or add to the Controller ?

This Question might sound very stupid, but i'm new to rails and cant get over that Problem.
If someone could enlighten me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your whole page is a shop, then there's no sense in making a single shop controller that contains every action of the shop. Instead, create controllers for the shops "parts". Normally, you would have a separate controller for static pages like `about` or `policy`.

Rails will, by default, search for a file that has the same name as the action of the controller under the folder with the same name as the controller and load it, after the code in the controller is executed.

So, if your controller is Shop, and the action is policy, just add a `policy.html.erb` file under the `views/shop folder`. Finally, add this to the routes.rb file:

```
get 'shop/test/about', to: 'shop#about'
```

Consider the [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), which covers all this.

Comment: I have a lot of controllers and my Website is not only the "Shop", if its that what you mean. If you know the Solution, do you mind editing your answer so it could actually Help me ? Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. Then, unless the shop has really just a few actions, you probably still want to split the shop functionality between several controllers. And then, even if your page has other things a part from the shop and these policy and about pages are shop-specific, I would still put them in a separate controller, either a specific shop-static-pages controller or on the general-static-pages controller, however you want to name them.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Rails so i don't quite understand what you really want to Say. So you suggest i generate a ,for example, General_static_pages Controller and then add those pages to my shop? The Problem here is, in the first place, i don't know HOW to put a page to a controller and then assign it so the url shows up as i described in the Question Above.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I understood your question as a design question, like, what's the best approach. Rails will, by default, search for a file that has the same name as the action of the controller under the folder with the same name as the controller and load it after the code in the controller is executed. So, if your controller is Shop, and the action is policy, just add a policy.html.erb file under the views/shop folder.

Comment: Ohhh, nice! Now we are talking :) Cool, now how do i edit the routes so  localhost:3000/shop/test/about works ?

Comment: Add this to the routes.rb file:   get 'shop/test/about', to: 'shop#about'   . You can find all this info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html But I really encourage you to do the blog tutorial, it covers every basic thing, included everything you asked: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you mind Editing your answer with the info you gave me so i can upvote you and others can see it too?